# convert var(a,b) to var(b,a) in VI

Tags: vi, vim

Is it possible with any command to convert this

```
flux(1,i)
flux(2,i)
flux(3,i)
flux(4,i)
flux(5,i)
```

to this in VI?

```
flux(i,1)
flux(i,2)
flux(i,3)
flux(i,4)
flux(i,5)
```

In general i want to convert `flux(a,b)` to `flux(b,a)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a replace regex, swapping the two groups around the comma:

```
:%s/flux(\([^,]*\),\([^)]*\))/flux(\2,\1)/
```

Broken down:

```
:%s/       #global replace
flux(      #find 'flux('
\([^,]*\), #match everything until a comma into group 1
\([^)]*\)) #match everything until a ')' into group 2
/          #replace with:
flux(      #text 'flux('
\2,\1      #group 2, followed by group 1
)/         #close parenthesis and end match
```

Add a `g` on the end if there is more than one flux call on a single line.

Comment: If I have a 4D array and want to switch the first and last dimension, then should I split them into 4 groups and then order them as `\4,\2,\3,\1` ?

Comment: @arunmoezhi - should work. You could also put 2 and 3 into a single group, as you're not separating them. Then you'd only have 3 groups, and you'll just swap 1 and 3.

Comment: I tried and it worked. This regex saved me more than 4 hrs of work. thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

You could use a substitution:

```
:%s/\([0-9]\),i/i,\1/g
```

This will turn every appearance of <digit>,i into i,<digit>.

Comment: This almost works. But i have this scenario as well:
`flux(m,i+1)` to `flux(i+1,m)`

Comment: Tim's answer, based on the same idea, has a more robust substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Here's one way for your given input, starting with the cursor on the first f:

`f1<c-q>4jxlphh<c-q>4jxp`

Answer (score 1):

From command mode:

```
:%! m4 -Dflux='`flux($2,$1)'"'"
```

This will run the current buffer through `m4` to do the substitutions.  Note that
this will correctly replace input which spans newlines or contains nested parentheses or is recursive.  For example,

```
flux(text that contains parens
  and (spans) a newline,flux( q, r ) )
```

Will be replaced with

```
flux(flux(r ,q) ,text that contains parens
  and (spans) a newline)
```

If the nested parens do not match, you will get an error.  Also, leading spaces on any arguments to flux will be discarded, but this is a much more robust solution that anything you might try to do with regex matching.

Comment: Can I ask what this does? I tried running this in my vim and it said "Shell returned 1, 5 lines filtered", and it replaces all the text in my document with `Unmatched (backtick).`

Comment: This runs the contents of the buffer through `m4`, and replaces the content of the buffer with its output.  The `Unmatched (backtick)` is an error message from your shell.  Perhaps you did not include the backslash before the backquote.  Try a different quoting style: `:$! m4 -Dflux=''flux($2,$1)'"'"`  (The single quote before `flux` should be a backquote, but I do not know how to escape that in an SO comment.)

Comment: @BerNhard I strongly disagree.  This sort of replacement can become very complex (consider the case where the arguments span newlines, or contain multiply nested brackets/parentheses) and there are many powerful tools that already exist that handle those cases very well.  `m4` is very well suited to this task.  Re-inventing the wheel is a bad idea, and the reason `vi` and `vim` fit so well in the unix environment is that they provide excellent support for the philosophy of re-using existing tools.  I would argue that built-in commands should be avoided whenever possible.